# Sticky navigation item stays active when div is not present on page

Tags: javascript, typescript, bootstrap-4, navigation, sticky

I am experiencing an issue where one of the sticky nav items has active class when page is loaded. What's weird is that the div which corresponds to the nav link is not present on the page. How can I make sure that the active class is not set to the nav link when the linked div is not present on page?

```
  $(window).scroll((): void => {
    const windowOffset = $(window).scrollTop() || 0;
    const navItems = $('.nav-section.sticky-top .navbar .nav .nav-link');

    navItems.each(function (): void {
      const href = $(this).attr('href');

      if (href !== undefined && href !== '#') {
        const targetDiv = $(href);

        if (targetDiv !== undefined && targetDiv.attr('#') !== '#') {
          const offset = targetDiv.offset();
          const top = offset !== undefined ? offset.top : 0;
          const topOffset =
            $('.nav-section-subtitle') !== undefined &&
            $('.nav-section-subtitle').hasClass('d-md-block')
              ? 165
              : 145;

          if (top - topOffset <= windowOffset) {
            const targetAnchor = $(`.nav-section.sticky-top a[href="${href}"]`);
            if (!targetAnchor.parent().hasClass('active')) {
              $(
                '.nav-section.sticky-top .navbar .nav .nav-item.active'
              ).removeClass('active');
              targetAnchor.parent().addClass('active');

              $('.nav-section.sticky-top .navbar')[0].scrollLeft =
                targetAnchor[0].offsetLeft - 20;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
      });
```

HTML

```
 <div class="nav-section mb-20 sticky-top loaded stuck" style="">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <nav class="navbar">
               <ul class="nav">
                  <li class="nav-item" data-show-at="128.0469" aria-hidden="false">
                     <a href="#content_container_2639899" class="nav-link ga-event">About</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" data-show-at="214.7656" aria-hidden="false">
                     <a href="#content_container_2639901" class="nav-link ga-event">Research</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" data-show-at="292.9062" aria-hidden="false">
                     <a href="#content_container_2639903" class="nav-link ga-event">Projects</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" data-show-at="76.625" aria-hidden="false" style="">
                     <a href="#content_container_2639921" class="nav-link ga-event">Partners</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item last-item" data-show-at="76.625" aria-hidden="false" style="">
                     <a href="#content_container_2639923" class="nav-link ga-event">Next steps</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </nav>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

SASS

```
@media #{$breakpoint-lg-up}
  .nav-section
    max-width: 100%
    display: block
    width: 100%

    .navbar
      overflow: hidden

      .nav
        .nav-item
          .nav-link
            &:focus
              background-color: $colour-sweet-corn
          &.active
            .nav-link:focus
              color: darken($colour-red, 5%)

          &.dropdown-more
            .dropdown-menu-more
              @include border-radius(0)
              padding-top: 0
              padding-bottom: 0
              margin-top: 0
              background-color: $colour-white
              box-shadow: 0px #{($base-unit*0.5)} $base-unit 0px rgba($colour-black,0.1)
              border: none

              .nav-item
                padding: 0
                width: 100%

                .nav-link
                  padding: $base-unit*0.75 $base-unit*1.5
                  font-size: map-get($font-17, 'size')
                  white-space: nowrap
                  border: none
                  border-left: $base-unit*0.4 solid $colour-white

            &:hover
              .dropdown-toggle
                border-color: $colour-transparent

            .nav-item
              .nav-link
                color: $colour-grey-darker
                text-shadow: none
                padding: ($base-unit*1.5)

                &:focus
                  border-left-color: $colour-sweet-corn

                &:hover
                  border-color: $colour-tint-prime

              &.active
                .nav-link
                  border-left: $base-unit*0.4 solid $colour-red
                  color: $colour-red

                  &:hover
                    border-left: $base-unit*0.4 solid $colour-red
                    color: $colour-red

            &:hover
              color: $colour-grey-darkest

              .dropdown-menu
                display: block

    &.loaded
      .navbar
        overflow: visible

    &:after
      content: unset
```

Comment: your HTML and CSS would help debug this perplexing issue

Comment: Sorry, added them in